# Did not find handler method with JAX-RS

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

I have a resource JAX-RS

```
@Path("/profile")
public class ProfileResource {

    @GET
    @Path(value = "/{username}")
    public Response getProfile(
            @PathParam("username") String username,
            @Context UriInfo uriInfo
    ) throws URISyntaxException {
       ....
    }
}



    2017-07-29 20:37:41.940 DEBUG 4004 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Successfully completed request
2017-07-29 20:38:01.223 DEBUG 4004 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/profile/jonki]
2017-07-29 20:38:01.236 DEBUG 4004 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /profile/jonki
2017-07-29 20:38:01.236 DEBUG 4004 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Did not find handler method for [/profile/jonki]
2017-07-29 20:38:01.237 DEBUG 4004 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Matching patterns for request [/profile/jonki] are [/**]
2017-07-29 20:38:01.237 DEBUG 4004 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : URI Template variables for request [/profile/jonki] are {}
2017-07-29 20:38:01.237 DEBUG 4004 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapping [/profile/jonki] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [ResourceHttpRequestHandler [locations=[ServletContext resource [/], class path resource [META-INF/resources/], class path resource [resources/], class path resource [static/], class path resource [public/]], resolvers=[org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver@36463b09]]] and 1 interceptor
2017-07-29 20:38:01.237 DEBUG 4004 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Last-Modified value for [/profile/jonki] is: -1
2017-07-29 20:38:01.238 DEBUG 4004 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
2017-07-29 20:38:01.238 DEBUG 4004 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Successfully completed request
2017-07-29 20:38:01.238 DEBUG 4004 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/error]
2017-07-29 20:38:01.239 DEBUG 4004 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /error
```

I do not find a method with JAX-RS. I am using Spring Boot and have not done any configuration.

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing up tech for no reason. Spring has it's own web framework, there's no need for JAX-RS, and Spring Web is not JAX-RS compliant anyway, which explains why the handler didn't get registered. See [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/getting-started-first-application.html). It is possible to use JAX-RS with Spring dependency injection, but unnecessary. See [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-jersey).

Comment: I don't like the assumptions made in this answer.

Comment: @sschrass You don't have to.

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured jaxrs in spring boot to look for rest resources in the ProfileResource package (or at least specifically registered your class)?

I suggest you reading spring boot documentation on that matter [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html) section 27.2